# Upload image and show it in tile format if image size smaller then Container Div Size

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, file-upload

I am creating a website.

And I need to create a page in that. I need to implement these features:

1. User can upload an image.
2. After Uploading it, he/She can See That Picture.
3. I have a fixed area with width of 500px in that user can  see his/her picture after uploading.
4. If the user uploads a small size image. That image would not stretch it will Fill The Area with tile Format.
5. It is like our desktop background.

Please help me on this.

Comment: @spiny-norman Would you mind to explain why you rolled back my edit?

Comment: @Spontifixus I believe I rolled back an edit that changed "features" to "feature" and removed the list formatting. Also, it was by somebody else. I have a feeling something went wrong. Please excuse me if I accidentally threw out your changes as well. Maybe you can redo your edit?

Comment: @SpinyNorman: This is a numbered list - so I will re-add the list formatting, and everything should be fine... ;)

Answer (score 0):

For 
1. Use ajax file upload control (or) normal aspx file upload control for multiple photos to add
2. Use image control 
3. Set that image control width as 500px
4. In image control its having option to locate an image
5. You can resize it as u want to display

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript like..

```
width = 0;
while (width<500){ // 500 the max width
diva.innerHtml+='insert image' // code to append the image in the div
width+=insertimage.width // code to set the total width that has been used
}
```

You can also do it for height
* note:- the above code is for illustration purpose only, you will need to change it.
      here i ahve written a sample code for you

```
<head>
<title></title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function Button1_onclick() {
        var h = document.getElementById("Text1");
        var im = document.getElementById("Text3");
        var dimage = document.getElementById("div1");
        dimage.setAttribute("style", "width:" + h.value);
        width = 0;
        dimage.innerHTML = " ";
        while (width < h.value) {
            dimage.innerHTML += "<img alt=\"\"src = \"" + im.value + "\"/>";
            width += 100;
        }

    }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .style1
    {
        height: 23px;
    }
</style>
```

```
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Max Width</td>
        <td>
            <input id="Text1" type="text" value="600" /></td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Max Height</td>
        <td>
            <input id="Text2" type="text" value="500" /></td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Image Location</td>
        <td>
            <input id="Text3" type="text" 
                value="www.conflictprevention-ks.org/images/img.jpg" /></td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Load Image" onclick="return Button1_onclick()" /></td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="style1">
            <div id="div1">
             </div>
        </td>
        <td class="style1">
            </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

just save the code a html file and see how it is working.